# nginx server and node.js running faulty

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I have nginx server installed and node.js on my local machine. I have the following node.js server:

```
//app.js
var fs = require("fs");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

//app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/", function(request, response){
    var content = fs.readFileSync("index.html");
    content = content.toString("utf8").replace("{{TEXT}}", "Home");
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    response.send(content);
});

app.get("/hello/:text", function(request, response) {
var content = fs.readFileSync("index.html");
    content = content.toString("utf8").replace("{{TEXT}}", request.params.text);
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    response.send(content);
}); 

app.listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

If I run nginx server, **localhost** I get the HTML page,but the "{{TEXT}}"" is not replaced. If I run **localhost/hello/hi** I get the following message: 500 Internal Server Error.

So, in my folder I have the file app.js and another folder called **public**. In **public** I have an index.html file.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, here is my nginx configuration:

```
upstream app_nodejs {
server 127.0.0.1:1337;
}

server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;

server_name localhost;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://app_nodejs;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}

location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow ::1;
    deny all;
}
}
```

Comment: Update: Now, if I run it at localhost, I get the text changed. But if i run at localhost/hello/hi I get: Cannot GET /index.html . All changes are updated up.

Comment: Hi Dan. We prefer answers in answers here, rather than as addendums to questions. If you would like to supply a solution for another question in the future, we encourage self-answers here (even if you accept another answer). I've moved it for you just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx is running correctly on, but node probably isn't. In most cases, you can't run two servers on the same port, and that seems to be causing the problem.
Figure out which port node is running on, and make nginx pipe to it, when the file is not static.

Comment: I don't think that node isn't function correctly. With the changes made, the node.js code is running on "/".  If i try it at localhost:1337 all works well. The connection between nginx and node is the problem, I guess. And also, nginx is on 80 and node is on 1337.

Comment: Thank you, your answer "inspired" me to find out what was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

*Posted on behalf of OP.*

## Solved!

In the nginx config, I added a location for the custom route:

```
location /hello/ {
    location ~* {

proxy_pass http://app_nodejs;

    }
}
```

Also, for the other routes that are not defined, I caught them in app.js:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
   res.send('Not found! Send the 404.html', 404);
});
```